# How can I use SOCAT to mount a TCP/AES encrypted serial line as a Linux device?

Tags: linux

How can I use SOCAT to mount a TCP/AES encrypted serial line as a Linux device? I am currently able to mount the non-encrypted serial line using the command below:

```
socat -d -d pty,link=/dev/serdev001,raw,echo=0,waitslave tcp:10.0.0.1:11000
```

Comment: How do you propose to decrypt the data?

Comment: Its TCP/AES encrypted, I am open to use any third party script to decrypt it. But how do it attach it to socat?